# QPSK function operation/MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, telecommunication, phase, modulation

QPSK Modulation its supposed to use 2 bits for each symbol, but wheter I use pskmod or comm.QPSKModulator, I'm still getting the same amount of symbols as bits. Am i doing something wrong? Is something wrong with the function? Thanks in advance.

```
M=4;
n=64;
m=log2(M);
x=round(rand(n*m,1));
mod = comm.QPSKModulator;
xmod1 = mod(x);
xmod=pskmod(x,M,pi/M,'gray');
```

[Variables in Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAVZL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `pskmod` function expects an input consisting of **symbols** as numbers in the range `0`, ..., `M-1`, not bits. That is, it modulates the symbols into complex values, but doesn't do the mapping from bits to symbols. This is also the default behaviour of the `comm.QPSKModulator` object.

To include the **bit-to-symbol mapping** as part of the modulator, and thus use input in the form of bits, set the `BitInput` property of the `comm.QPSKModulator` object to `true`.  This can be done directly when creating the object, by passing the inputs `'BitInput', true` to the constructor:

```
modQPSK = comm.QPSKModulator('BitInput', true);
xmod1 = modQPSK(x);
```

Also, note that I've changed the name of the object to avoid shadowing the built-in function `mod`.